# Issue with nnmaildir in gnus

Tags: gnus

I've been trying to get nnmaildir to work along with mbsync (which syncs IMAP and Maildir mailboxes) and I just cannot get it to work with gnus.

With the following select method:

```
(nnmaildir "calgary"
           (directory "~/mail/ucalgary"))
```

I can open the connection and the server browse buffer shows all the groups:

```
K      0: Calendar
U      0: Inbox
K      0: Sent Items
```

When I open the Inbox I get the following error:

```
gnus-select-newsgroup: Couldn't request group nnmaildir+calgary:Inbox: No such group: Inbox
```

Now if I look in `/home/crb/mail/ucalgary/Inbox/cur/` there are a number of read and unread messages for example `1443481160.3793_16.Feddie,U=16:2,S`.

Any advice on how to fix this?

Comment: im also extremely interested in this. do you have to use devcot for this or can gnus just read a maildir mbsync folder?

Comment: @zeltak Just linking [your corresponding question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/34274/15748) here for posterity

Answer (score 0):

> When I open the Inbox

I assume by this you mean you typed `RET` on the `Inbox` group when browsing the `nnmaildir` virtual server. When I ran into this problem, typing `u` (i.e. `gnus-browse-unsubscribe-current-group`) over the group in question first solved the problem. My guess is that subscribing to the group first moves the Maildir files to the expected place, but I know very little about the underlying operations and formats, so take this with a pinch of salt.